# How do I reference multiple values Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference, snapshot

I need to reference and query the two values "8R6ZAojX0FNO7aSd2mm5aQXQFpk1", "GGqjtYvwSwQw9hQCVpF4lHN0kMI3".

```
jobs
 "Post ID"
   applicants:
     -KtLJaQnFMnyI-MDWpys:"8R6ZAojX0FNO7aSd2mm5aQXQFpk1"
     -KtLLBFU_aVS_xfSpw1k:"GGqjtYvwSwQw9hQCVpF4lHN0kMI3"
```

This is what I have so far

```
let appRef = self.ref.child("jobs").child(self.job.postID).child("applicants")
            appRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let sValue = "\(snapshot.value!)"
                print (sValue)
            })
```

But it only prints one value, I'm guessing I need to use a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using observeSingleEvent here. It is observing only first event.
You need:

```
appRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Don't forget to choose answer :)